# Операции над многомерным массивом - перемещение и удаление

Tags: php

Задан многомерный массив такого вида:

```
$sections = [

    "section1" => [
        'id' => 123,
        "name" => 'section name',
        "sub" => [
            "sub-sec-2" => [
                'id' => 223,
                "name" => 'section name 2',
            ],
            "sub-sec-4" => [
                'id' => 2523,
                "name" => 'section name 5',
            ]
        ]
    ],
    "section3" => [
        "id" => 555,
        "name" => 'other name',
        "sub" => [
            ...
        ]
    ]

];
```

Есть ли библиотека, которая позволяет перемещать одни подразделы в другие из текущего массива? Удаление и т.д.

Команды перемещения передаются в таком формате

```
[
   'from' => ['section 6', 'subsect 4', 'sect 7'],
   'to' => ["section 1", "subsection 1", ...]
]
```

Элементы `from` и `to` - это поля `name` из главного массива.

Comment: Есть. Называется `__set()` и `__unset()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотри фреймворк laravel. В его состав входит пакет [`Illuminate\support`](https://github.com/illuminate/support), в частности есть класс `Illuminate\Support\Arr`
Доступ к элементам массива через dot-notation (через точку), например к элементу массива `$arr['parent']['child']` при помощи этого хэлпера можно получить так `Arr::get($arr, 'parent.child')`. Подробнее почитеть можно тут - https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers

Касательно твоего вопроса

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

$sections = [/* ... */];

// Получить элемент массива и удалить его со старого места
$el = Arr::pull($sections, 'section6.subsect4.sect7');
// Вставить элемент на новое место
Arr::set($sections, 'section1.subsection1', $el);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

А как быть, если мне нужно получать доступ к элементам не по ключам, а по одному из элементов подмассива? Т.е. по полю `name`. В моем случае `name` это название разделов, которая содержит кириллицу и пробелы.

Comment: Поиск по массиву - цикл или `array_filter()`